# Salesforce and JIRA integration using OAuth

Tags: community

For last few days I am trying to figure out the ways of implementing this type of integration using OAuth.

I've got a community from which I wanna make requests to JIRA to create/get/delete/edit issues. I have no problem with making these requests, using basic authentication, but I am tasked to do it, using OAuth.

So, I've got several questions:

1. What needs to be configured (on org and on JIRA side)?
2. What data do we need to store in org for that?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: Well, maybe, a little. But is creating of named credentials and auth providers the only way of implementing it? And still, what do i need to configure on Jira side?

Comment: If you haven't already, you should be reading through Jira's documentation as well. Any system worth its salt is going to have detailed documentation about submitting requests to it (and what you need to do in terms of authentication).

Comment: I've spent several days on learning this docs, and there are a few examples for Java, but I am asking for help with configuration of Salesforce org and Jira client. Named credentials and auth providers are obligatory for configuring this integration?